# Python Regex: Extract all occurences of a substring within a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to extract all occurrences of a substring within a string using Python Regex. This is what I have tried:

```
import re
line = "The dimensions of the first rectangle: 10'x20', second rectangle: 10x35cm, third rectangle: 30x35cm"
m = re.findall(r'\d+x.*?[a-zA-Z]', line)
print (m)
```

The output I am getting is `['10x35c', '30x35c']`

The output I am trying to achieve is `['10'x20'', '10x35cm', '30x35cm']`

Comment: You may use this regex: `\d+'?x\d+'?(?:[a-zA-Z]+)?`

Comment: Try to explain in english what you are trying tô extract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
r"\d+['\"]?x\d+['\"]?(?:\s*[a-zA-Z]+)?"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T0fghH/2)

**Code:**

```sh
>>> import re
>>> line = "The dimensions of the first rectangle: 10'x20', second rectangle: 10x35cm, third rectangle: 30x35cm"
>>> print (re.findall(r"\d+['\"]?x\d+['\"]?(?:\s*[a-zA-Z]+)?", line))
["10'x20'", '10x35cm', '30x35cm']
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `\d+`: Match 1+ digits
- `['\"]?`: Match optional `'` or `"`
- `x`: Match letter `x`
- `\d+`: Match 1+ digits
- `['\"]?`: Match optional `'` or `"`
- `(?:\s*[a-zA-Z]+)?`: Match optional units comprising 1+ letters

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without `regex` using **[`split`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)**:

```
In [1089]: m = [i.split(':')[1].strip() for i in line.split(',')]

In [1090]: m
Out[1090]: ["10'x20'", '10x35cm', '30x35cm']
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind effort, but I wanted to use regex though.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
import re
string = "The dimensions of the first rectangle: 10'x20', second rectangle: 10x35cm, third rectangle: 30x35cm"
print(re.findall(r"""\d+'?x\d+'?(?: *[a-z]+)?""", string, re.I))
```

**Results**: `["10'x20'", '10x35cm', '30x35cm']`

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##VY6xDoIwEIZ3nuLSpUWQoMSFxDC7u6kDoQUugSu5dkBfvlacWG647//vu@XtR0tVCDgvlj2wSZxnpAGuIO6jAY2zIYeWHNgefNz0yO4X7HxLw2RqOJVyPZcyB2c6S3qP1urSzXksIu9I9SciWaLNKzZFj6TbaVIshHjqTDbrNlVTw@HRHj@vLG0iiprtwTxeK25pGsIX). `re.I` stands for case insensitive matching.

**Explanation**:

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  '?                       '\'' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  x                        'x'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  '?                       '\'' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *                       ' ' (0 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]+                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
```